# JavaScript equivalent of Ruby's String#scan

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

Does this exist?

I need to parse a string like:

```
the dog from the tree
```

and get something like

```
[[null, "the dog"], ["from", "the tree"]]
```

which I can do in Ruby with one RegExp and `String#scan`.

JavaScript's `String#match` cannot handle this as it just return what the RegExp is matched and not the capturing groups, so it returns something like

```
["the dog", "from the tree"]
```

Because I used `String#scan` many times in my Ruby application, it would be nice if there was a quick way to replicate this behavior in my JavaScript port.

EDIT: Here is the RegExp I'm using: http://pastebin.com/bncXtgYA

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
String.prototype.scan = function (re) {
    if (!re.global) throw "Regexp should contain /g modifier at the end"
    var s = this
    var m, r = []
    while (m = re.exec(s)) {
        m.shift()
        r.push(m)
    }
    return r
};
```

Comment: I added this to my code and directly replaced `.match` to `.scan` but it still doesn't work. Here is the RegExp I'm using: http://pastebin.com/bncXtgYA (test string: `"the dog in the tree"`) I copied that RegExp directly from Ruby and I'm new to JS RegExp so there may be some problems with it.

Comment: "*doesn't work*" is meaningless. I tried `"the dog in the tree".scan(/(?:(in|into|to|at|from) )?((?:(?:the|a|an) )?(?:\d+\.|all\.)?(?:\w+|'[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*?'))/gi)` and got `[[undefined, "the dog"], ["in", "the tree"]]`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm a dum-dum and I didn't read the output correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

ruby's scan() method will return nested array only when capture group is specified.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan

```
a = "cruel world"
a.scan(/\w+/)        #=> ["cruel", "world"]
a.scan(/.../)        #=> ["cru", "el ", "wor"]
a.scan(/(...)/)      #=> [["cru"], ["el "], ["wor"]]
a.scan(/(..)(..)/)   #=> [["cr", "ue"], ["l ", "wo"]]
```

Below is modified version of melpomene's answer to return flat array if appropriate.

```
function scan(str, regexp) {
    if (!regexp.global) {
        throw new Error("RegExp without global (g) flag is not supported.");
    }
    var result = [];
    var m;
    while (m = regexp.exec(str)) {
        if (m.length >= 2) {
            result.push(m.slice(1));
        } else {
            result.push(m[0]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I found the solution useful, but without an explanation on the original solution from  @melpomeme , please can you explain why the global flag is required?

Answer (score 5):

Here's another implementation using `String.replace`:

```
String.prototype.scan = function(regex) {
    if (!regex.global) throw "regex must have 'global' flag set";
    var r = []
    this.replace(regex, function() {
        r.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, -2));
    });
    return r;
}
```

How it works: `replace` will invoke the callback on every match, passing it the matched substring, the matched groups, the offset, and the full string. We only want the matched groups, so we `slice` out the other arguments.

Comment: I've seen this mentioned before, but never understood how something like this would be implemented. I'll try it now. Thanks!

Comment: And, by the way, here is the RegExp I'm using. Is there anything I'm doing horribly wrong? http://pastebin.com/bncXtgYA

Comment: @itdoesntwork it works for me in Chrome. What browser / browser version are you using?

Comment: Chrome, and it works. Since I directly copied this from Ruby, there might have been something wrong conventionally. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a matching of all incidents of a regexp without capture groups--which the original poster was not, but which may be desired by those landing here from Google--you want to use JavaScript's [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) along with a `g`lobal flag on the RegExp:

```rb
ruby -e "p '12h 37m'.scan /\d+/"
#=> ["12", "37"]
```

```js
node -e "console.log('12h 37m'.match(/\d+/g))"
// [ '12', '37' ]
```

If capture groups are important, then the [`String.prototype.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) method may instead be desired:

```js
console.log(Array.from('12h 37m'.matchAll(/(\d+)(.)/g)))
// [
//   [ '12h', '12', 'h', index: 0, input: '12h 37m', groups: undefined ],
//   [ '37m', '37', 'm', index: 4, input: '12h 37m', groups: undefined ]
// ]
```

The results of this can be used for functional transformation by extracting the non-zero numerical entries from each result using `slice()`:

```js
Array.from('12h 37m'.matchAll(/(\d+)(.)/g))).flatMap( m => m.slice(1) )
// [ '12', 'h', '37', 'm' ]
```

Wrapping this up as a convenient extension on the prototype as others have done:

```js
if (!String.prototype.scan) String.prototype.scan = function(re) {
    if (!re.global) {
        throw new Error("String#scan requires RegExp with global (g) flag")
    }
    return Array.from(this.matchAll(re))
                .flatMap(m => m.length > 1 ? m.slice(1) : m[0])
}

const str = '12h 37m'

console.log(str.scan(/\d+/g))
// [ '12', '37' ]

console.log(str.scan(/(\d+)(.)/g))
// [ '12', 'h', '37', 'm' ]
```