# How to reference second and third regexp match in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I reference match 2 and match 3 of a regexp?

http://rubular.com/r/faAwIE98uz

I know I can reference several match groups with $1 and $2 and so on, but I want to reference just the matches of a single group.

--update--

I want to use this regexp `(\d{1,3})` with the input `123456789` and reference these matches:

Match 1

1. 123

Match 2

1. 456

Match 3

1. 789

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Can you post your example here, and then show which matches/parts you want to reference?

Comment: Use this `"123456789".scan(/(.{1,3})/) # => [["123"], ["456"], ["789"]]`. Now you have an array,and you can access the elements as you wish.

Comment: thanks for the ruby answer @ArupRakshit ! do you have one for javascript as well?

Comment: @Magne http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895373/javascript-equivalent-of-rubys-stringscan

Comment: @MarkThomas Thanks! So `"123456789".match("(\d{1,3})")` is the method, and I get an array from it, so I can get the second and third match from there. Solves my problem. Do you want to add an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, you can use the `g` modifier on the `match` method:

```
var matches_array = str.match(/\d{1,3}/g);
```

Then you can pick the items you want from the array.