# Regex help - include, but not show

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a `this.responseText`, which is messy. Trying to separate the ones that I need:

Here's the text:

```
<html>
<head><title>Index of /browserify-view/build/source/pic/</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Index of /browserify-view/build/source/pic/</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="wd0c9af04bbf54efc9a2f7ba766a6694f2421b1dc.png">wd0c9af04bbf54efc9a2f7ba766a6694f2421b1dc..&gt;</a> 22-Jul-2016 22:29               65180
<a href="thumb-wd20f381801bb51.png">thumb-wd20f381801bb51.png;</a> 22-Jul-2016 22:33               10779
</pre><hr></body>
</html>
```

How can I separate like this:

```
wd0c9af04bbf54efc9a2f7ba766a6694f2421b1dc.png

thumb-wd20f381801bb51.png
```

Comment: Add javascript tag if it is.

Comment: ^(?=.*(?:a href|.png|...))

Comment: Why am I getting minuses? What is wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## First of all, *DO NOT* do this with Regex!

## [Regex is *NOT* capable of parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)!

---

Use the javascript [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) instead:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(this.responseText, 'text/html');
```

Then use the DOM API to get the elements you need:

```
var nodes = doc.querySelectorAll('a:not([href="../"])');
```

And finally, use `Array.map` to map the nodes to their `href` attributes:

```
// Can't use nodes.map here because nodes in a NodeList, not an array
var links = Array.prototype.map.call(nodes, function(element)
{
    // Can't use element.href here because we're in a different document
    return element.getAttribute('href');
});
```

If you put that all together:

```js
var exampleResponseText = `<html>
<head><title>Index of /browserify-view/build/source/pic/</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Index of /browserify-view/build/source/pic/</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="wd0c9af04bbf54efc9a2f7ba766a6694f2421b1dc.png">wd0c9af04bbf54efc9a2f7ba766a6694f2421b1dc..&gt;</a> 22-Jul-2016 22:29               65180
<a href="thumb-wd20f381801bb51.png">thumb-wd20f381801bb51.png;</a> 22-Jul-2016 22:33               10779
</pre><hr></body>
</html>`;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(exampleResponseText, 'text/html');
var nodes = doc.querySelectorAll('a:not([href="../"])');
var links = Array.prototype.map.call(nodes, function(element)
{
    return element.getAttribute('href');
});

console.log(links);
```

Comment: Million times amazing. Thanks a lot Siguza!

Answer (score 0):

This is by far one of the best responses I've seen on this topic:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

If you are trying to do something quick, I would look to something like this (python):

```
<a[^>]+href="(?P<x>[^"]+)">
```

Just note, its bad practice and if this is going to be executed on a larger scale (anything besides just THIS html) I would recommend an html parser. It will save a lot of time in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
str.scan(/(?<=<a href=").+?\.png/)
```

This will return an array:

```
["wd0c9af04bbf54efc9a2f7ba766a6694f2421b1dc.png", "thumb-wd20f381801bb51.png"]
```

To break down the regex

```
/(?<=<a href=").+?\.png/
```

- `(?<=<a href=")` is a positive look behind, which matches the `<a href="` string before the main expression without including it in the result.
- `.+?` matches any character 1 or more times, with the lazy operator, which matches the smallest number of characters possible.
- `\.png` matches the `.png`

Comment: [Using Regex on HTML is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).

Comment: The question is about javascript

Comment: oh sorry, but the regex will work in js. you can check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895373/javascript-equivalent-of-rubys-stringscan) on how to implement the `scan` method in javascript.