# Split string by multiple delimiters, keep them and ignore them in double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, split, jscript, wsh

I know this question had been asked before in numerous variations but I can't seem to merge all the data to a working solution

#### Motivation

I have a `JScript` running under `WSH`. However, this is essentially a simple `javascript` | `regexp` question

I'm trying to parse a string. requirements:

1. Split it by multiple delimiters: `-`, `=`
2. Ignore delimiters wrapped in double quotes
3. Keep the delimiters in the result

#### Example

This is the string I've been working with. double quotes are part of the string

```
"C:\\Users\\u 1\\a-b\\f1.txt" -CONFIG="C:\\Users\\u 1\\c=d\\f2.xfg"-ARGS=/quite /v1
```

expected results after split

1. `"C:\\Users\\u 1\\a-b\\f1.txt"`
2. `-`
3. `CONFIG`
4. `=`
5. `"C:\\Users\\u 1\\c=d\\f2.xfg"`
6. `-`
7. `ARGS`
8. `=`
9. `/quite /v1`

#### Failed attempt

```
var str = '"C:\\Users\\u 1\\a-b\\f1.txt" -CONFIG="C:\\Users\\u 1\\c=d\\f2.xfg"-ARGS=/quite /v1';
var res = str .split(/-(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);
```

Failed Result:

1. `\"C:\\Users\\u 1\\a-b\\f1.txt`
2. `CONFIG=\"C:\\Users\\u 1\\c=d\\f2.xfg\"`
3. `ARGS=/quite /v1`

Comment: And what about escaped quotes (`\\"`)?

Comment: Seems like `Amadan` solution works well in that case

Comment: try `str.match(/"(?:\\[\s\S]|[^"])*"|[-=]|[^-="\s][^-="]*/g)`

Comment: @ndn: Indeed my code would not treat them correctly. It falls under my disclaimer (more test strings = better requirements = less weird corner case bugs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a weird thing to need... but here goes...

```js
var str = '"C:\\Users\\u 1\\a-b\\f1.txt" -CONFIG="C:\\Users\\u 1\\c=d\\f2.xfg"-ARGS=/quite /v1';
var res = [];
str.replace(/".*?"|-|=|[^-="\s]+(?:\s[^-="]+)?/g, function(m) { res.push(m); });
console.log(res);
```

`split` is tricky to use, as you need to define what you *don't* want; finding all matches is nicer (and in JavaScript, `replace` is the easiest way to do it - the other being the [`exec` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13895463/240443)). I'm picking out:

- quoted strings
- dashes
- equals
- strings of characters that do not fit the above

The fourth group would be a bit easier if `" "` was a valid thing to pick out, but you need to work a bit extra hard to disqualify plain blank spaces...

That said, you have only one example, so it might well break with other, untested input.

EDIT: wording, and simplification of the regex

EDIT2: for @ndn, a version that handles `\\n`:

```js
var str = '"C:\\Users\\u 1\\a-b\\f1.txt" -CONFIG="C:\\Users\\u\\"3\\"\\c=d\\f2.xfg"-ARGS=/quite /v1';
var res = [];
str.replace(/"(?:\\"|[^"])*"|-|=|[^-="\s]+(?:\s[^-="]+)?/g, function(m) { res.push(m); });
console.log(res);
```

Comment: there's no need to abuse `replace()` in this case. use `res = str.match(regex);` and imo `[^-="\s]+(?:\s[^-="]+)?` is a bit too specific I'd use `[^-="\s](?:[^-="]*[^-="\s])?` wich is basically a `[^-="]`+`trim()`